# ipython notebook multiple instances on different ports

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to have multiple instances of ipython notebook running on different ports for the same user. Is it possible?

Something like a list of ports for 'NotebookApp.port' with a default one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just run `jupyter notebook` a second time; it will automatically select another port to use.

Answer (score 14):

run `jupyter notebook --port=8090`

change 8090 for the port you want